# iOS app - An error occured while parsing Xaml: Data at the root level is invalid; Line 1 position 1 on my project file, .csproj

Tags: c#, ios, maui

I am in the process of converting my Xamarin IOS app to Maui and am having fits with the error described above. There is nothing pointing to anything that is helping me. I have searched and find nothing related to a project file, csproj. I am getting 2 errors on my project file and 2 on CSC which I have no idea what that means. I have tried taking portions out of my project file to narrow down where the error might be coming from but that is not helping. I am not sure what to do.
Here are the errors.

[image]

I find absolutely nothing in my project file that looks bad and I have searched through each one of my Xaml file in my project and find nothing wrong with them either. I even put my project file through an xml validator and the xml is valid. As this has to do with my project file and nothing to do with code, the other posts I have found do not help me. And on top of that, can someone please tell me where I find the problem noted as CSC. Here is my .csproj file. This was my Xamarin forms project which has now been converted to Maui... at least I think it has

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 <PropertyGroup>
<Configurations>Debug;Release;Ad-Hoc;AppStore</Configurations>
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
<UseMaui>True</UseMaui>
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
<SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<Compile Remove="DataAccess\Interfaces\**" />
<Compile Remove="Model\**" />
<Compile Remove="ResourceDictionary\**" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="DataAccess\Interfaces\**" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Model\**" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="ResourceDictionary\**" />
<None Remove="DataAccess\Interfaces\**" />
<None Remove="Model\**" />
<None Remove="ResourceDictionary\**" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Remove="DataAccess\MileageView.cs" />
<Compile Remove="Interfaces\IiCloud.cs" />
<Compile Remove="PopupPage.xaml.cs" />
<Compile Remove="Utilities\AutoPicker.cs" />
<Compile Remove="Utilities\CloudViewController.cs" />
<Compile Remove="Utilities\iCloud.cs" />
<Compile Remove="Utilities\PickerModule.cs" />
<Compile Remove="Utilities\PullToRefreshListView.cs" />
<Compile Remove="Utilities\RefreshControl.cs" />
<Compile Remove="Utilities\RefreshListVIew.cs" />
<Compile Remove="ViewControllersInterface.cs" />
<Compile Remove="Views\EditMileage.xaml.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<EmbeddedResource Remove="App.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="MainPage.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="PopupPage.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\EditMileage.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\EnterCar.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\EnterMileage.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\HelpMenu.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\HelpPages\EnterMileage.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\HelpPages\ViewMileage.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\iCloud.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\iCloudRestore.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\Note.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\SummaryMileage.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\TotalStats.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\UpdateCars.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\ViewMileage.xaml" />
<EmbeddedResource Remove="Views\ViewMileageDetail.xaml" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<None Remove="CroppedEnterCar.png" />
<None Remove="CroppedEnterMileage.png" />
<None Remove="CroppediCloud.png" />
<None Remove="CroppedMainMenu.png" />
<None Remove="CroppedMileageSummary.png" />
<None Remove="CroppedNewEnterCar.png" />
<None Remove="CroppedTotals.png" />
<None Remove="CroppedUpdateCar.png" />
<None Remove="CroppedUpdateMileage.png" />
<None Remove="CroppedViewMileage.png" />
<None Remove="ViewMileage.PNG" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<MauiImage Include="Images\croppedicloud.png" />
<MauiImage Include="Images\croppedupdatemileage.png" />
<MauiImage Include="Images\croppedentercar.png" />
<MauiImage Include="Images\croppedentermileage.png" />
<MauiImage Include="Images\croppedmainmenu.png" />
<MauiImage Include="Images\croppedmileagesummary.png" />
<MauiImage Include="Images\croppedtotals.png" />
<MauiImage Include="Images\croppedupdatecar.png" />
<MauiImage Include="Images\croppedviewmileage.png" />
<EmbeddedResource Include="ViewMileage.PNG" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Refractored.MvvmHelpers" Version="1.6.2" />
<PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter" Version="5.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes" Version="5.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Update="Views\Note.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Note.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\HelpMenu.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>HelpMenu.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\HelpPages\UpdateCar.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\HelpPages\UpdateMileage.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\HelpPages\EnterCar.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\HelpPages\EnterMileage.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>EnterMileage.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\HelpPages\MainMenu.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\HelpPages\MileageSummary.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\HelpPages\Totals.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\HelpPages\iCloud.cs">
  <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\HelpPages\ViewMileage.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>ViewMileage.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\iCloud.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>iCloud.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\TotalStats.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>TotalStats.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\iCloudRestore.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>iCloudRestore.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\UpdateCars.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>UpdateCars.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\EnterCar.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>EnterCar.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\SummaryMileage.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>SummaryMileage.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\ViewMileageDetail.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>ViewMileageDetail.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Update="Views\ViewMileage.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>ViewMileage.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<MauiXaml Update="Views\EditMileage.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
</MauiXaml>
<MauiXaml Update="Views\EnterCar.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
</MauiXaml>
<MauiXaml Update="Views\EnterMileage.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
</MauiXaml>
<MauiXaml Update="Views\HelpMenu.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
</MauiXaml>
<MauiXaml Update="Views\iCloud.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
</MauiXaml>
<MauiXaml Update="Views\iCloudRestore.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
</MauiXaml>
<MauiXaml Update="Views\Note.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
</MauiXaml>
<MauiXaml Update="Views\SummaryMileage.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
</MauiXaml>
<MauiXaml Update="Views\TotalStats.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
</MauiXaml>
<MauiXaml Update="Views\UpdateCars.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
</MauiXaml>
<MauiXaml Update="Views\ViewMileage.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
</MauiXaml>
<MauiXaml Update="Views\ViewMileageDetail.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
</MauiXaml>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Folder Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<MauiXaml Include="Views\EditMileage.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>EditMileage.xaml</DependentUpon>
</MauiXaml>
</ItemGroup>
<Target BeforeTargets="_CheckForTransitiveWindowsDesktopDependencies" Name="_FixStupidSdkError_NETSDK1136">
  <ItemGroup>
  <TransitiveFrameworkReference Remove="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" />
  <TransitiveFrameworkReference Remove="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF" />
  <TransitiveFrameworkReference Remove="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms" />
  <TransitiveFrameworkReference Remove="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" />
  <TransitiveFrameworkReference Remove="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" />
  <TransitiveFrameworkReference Remove="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" />
  <TransitiveFrameworkReference Remove="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" />
  <TransitiveFrameworkReference Remove="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
</Project>`
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Please do not post errors as images

Comment: Could you please post the full error message about this problem?

Comment: These are the full errors that are showing when I attempt to compile.. Those show as on the Errors tab, this is what shows on the output tab,
1>CSC : error MAUIG1001: An error occured while parsing Xaml: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.. This is why this is so hard for me to solve. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Based on the log you shared, there should be some error in your Xaml.  You can recheck the Xaml code of your app.

Comment: So, I have looked very closely at each one of my XAML files and find no error indications. I have also run each one through an XML validator incase I missed something and found nothing. I am not sure what else to do... any ideas? In addition, 2 of the error messages point to the csproj file which I do not create or alter so how can there be an error in there. As well I have looked very closely for any error indicators and have run that through an XML validator as well and there are no issues. I have no idea where to go from there, so if anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am not sure how I resolved the issue with the 2 errors pointing at the project file, other than I manually edited it a few times and one of those edits seemed to fix it, I cannot point to any the one that helped. But for the 2 errors that did not point to anything, I decided to take my XAML classes one at a time and exclude them from the project, compile them and then include them again and do that until I found the one causing the issue. It so happened that this approach worked and the first XAML I excluded and then included again fixed the issue.